# Set Timeout not decrementing param value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, settimeout

I am trying to make my setTimeout function reusable. But whenever I pass the `remainingTime` value, It does not decrement.

`console.log(remainingTime);` repeatedly returns `99` rather than decrementing ie `98`, `97`.

Any ideas?

```js
let remainingTimeToSolveQuiz = 100;
const timeRemainingEl = document.querySelector("#time-remaining");

function quizCountDown(remainingTime, elementToDisplayTime) {

  remainingTime--;
  console.log(remainingTime);

  if (remainingTime === 0) {
    // something
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  elementToDisplayTime.textContent = remainingTime;
}

let quizTimer = setInterval(quizCountDown, 1000, remainingTimeToSolveQuiz, timeRemainingEl);
```

```html
<div>
Time: <span id="time-remaining"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly, just debug the code. Put a breakpoint in `quizCountDown` and you'd see it's called with 100 every time it's called, because it's getting exactly the value of `remainingTimeToSolveQuiz` that you gave it in the first place. Note also that `clearTimeout(timer)` won't work because there is no variable `timer` in scope that represents a timer to clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setInterval` is calling the function every one second. Every time it is called you are passing the same params, one of which is a value of `100`. So every time your function is called, you are passing `100` and your function does what it is asked to do, subtract 1. That is why you see `99` repeat.

Solution:
A global variable to keep track of the time:

```js
let quizTime = 100; // global variable stores the quiz time

const timeRemainingEl = document.querySelector("#time-remaining");
let quizTimer;

function quizCountDown(elementToDisplayTime) {

  if (quizTime === 0) {
    // something
    clearTimeout(quizTimer);
  }
  elementToDisplayTime.textContent = quizTime;
  
  console.log(quizTime);
  quizTime--; // Calling this last starts your quiz timer with 100
}

quizTimer = setInterval(quizCountDown, 1000, timeRemainingEl);
```

```html
<div>
Time: <span id="time-remaining"></span>
</div>
```

Also, it helps to call `quizTime--` last. Because then your timer will show `100` initially.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in the initial value of `remainingTimeToSolveQuiz` into `setInterval`. This is passed by value, so it doesn't change with each loop.

So basically every time your `quizCountDown` function runs, it is using the initial value of `100` rather than the updated value.

Remove the `remainingTimeToSolveQuiz` passed into the interval and instead just use the real variable within your `quizCountDown` function.

Also make sure your `quizTimer` variable is initialized and that you reference it properly in `clearTimeout`.

```js
let quizTimer;

function quizCountDown(elementToDisplayTime) {

  remainingTimeToSolveQuiz--;
  console.log(remainingTime);

  if (remainingTimeToSolveQuiz === 0) {
    // something
    clearTimeout(quizTimer);
  }
  elementToDisplayTime.textContent = remainingTimeToSolveQuiz;
}

quizTimer = setInterval(quizCountDown, 1000, timeRemainingEl);
```

As a side note, I really don't recommend using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` if you want to measure accurate time. It will always be an approximation.

If you set an interval for 1000ms, it will always be a couple of milliseconds off, which can add up to large inaccuracies over a longer period of time.

A more effective approach would be to use timestamps to calculate the elapsed time since a stored initial starting point.